# Keep button pressed (inset) with CSS/HTML

Tags: css, html

Is there a CSS or HTML attribute to make a button look pressed when not pressing it?

I have searched a lot for this, but all I could find was tips for making your own CSS buttons with pressed effect. I am looking for a way to keep the standard HTML button (e.g. `<button type="submit"></button>`) in a pressed state **visually**. I do not try to actually press that button and fire events.

Comment: No, there is no CSS to do that. Yes, you'll have to apply your own styling. And be thorough; when you forget one property, the butons will look different across browsers and platforms.

Comment: what is your design interruption of a pressed button?

Comment: What do you mean by "design interruption"?

Comment: The intention is to have multiple buttons in a row, where I can select on of them, and then have it stay pressed. The state is handled on the server side, I would have just had to make it pressed visually. Now I have set it to be disabled, which works too to make it look pressed, but it would have been nice if it would actually look inset instead of just unclickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing something here.

First, there ist not standard HTML button. Browsers will render an unstyled `<button>foo</button>` based on their default styles, which are slightly different accross browsers and operating systems. Some browsers even allow the user to customize them. That's the reason for the existance of CSS resets/normalizers.

There might be a way to preset the state of a button but IMHO it makes no sense.

Instead of setting the state to get a certain style you should define your styles and use it for the button states.

Let's assume that our mental model of a clicked button is green:

```css
.always_clicked,
.always_clicked:active,
.always_clicked:hover {

  background: green;
  /* and the rest of our perception
   * of a clicked button
   * i.e. border-style:inset;
   *      inversed gradients ...
   */
}
```

```html
<button class="always_clicked">NousSommesUnis</button>
```

Comment: I thought it would make sense, because even though every browser has its own button design, all of them have states for default, hovering and clicked.